# "atg.project" was unable to instantiate class "atg.eclipse.project.wizard.ProjectWizard". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, atg, atg-dynamo

when i creating the new ATG project getting the below exception in eclipse

> The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in `atg.project` was
>   unable to instantiate class
>   `atg.eclipse.project.wizard.ProjectWizard`.
>   `java.lang.NullPointerException`

i already added the plugins and using the eclipse 64 bit kepler version, please suggest more on this. below is the exception stack trace 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atg.eclipse.framework.extension.ATGClassLoadingHook.addClassPathEntry(ATGClassLoadingHook.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.buildClasspath(ClasspathManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.initialize(ClasspathManager.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.initialize(DefaultClassLoader.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.createBCL(BundleLoader.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.createBCLPrevileged(BundleLoader.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.createClassLoader(BundleLoader.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1726)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(PreferenceDialog.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$4.run(PreferenceDialog.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createContents(PreferenceDialog.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.createDialogOn(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(PreferencesUtil.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(PreferencesUtil.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)

Comment: please suggest any changes regarding this..

Comment: please suggest steps to overcome this.

Comment: please suggest any on this i am unable to create new Atg project kindly help on this

Comment: kindly help on this issue please

Comment: below is the exception which i am observing on atgpreference

Comment: The ATG plugin is seriously old and I believe it is only supported on eclipse indigo.

Comment: thanks for suggestion ill try this.

Comment: i used the eclipse version indigo even for that also i am getting same kind of error, could you please suggest on this, even i set variable for DYNAMO_ROOT and DYNAMO_HOME

Comment: What is the error? What version of Java are you using to run eclipse?

Comment: exception i already mentioned above, and java 1.6 i am using and i tried kepler as well as indigo still i am getting the same above exception while creating the new ATG project and setting the ATG preferences also